# Error inflating class fragment Android Map v2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

> I know this is a duplicate question, but solutions from previous post doesn't worked for
>   me. Thats why am asking this question.

I am trying to implement Google Map V2 in Android App, I got below error

```
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.titutorial.mapdemo/com.titutorial.mapdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at com.titutorial.mapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     ... 11 more
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4849)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     ... 20 more
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
06-26 19:24:51.035: E/AndroidRuntime(7679):     ... 23 more
```

I followed below tutorial,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

I did below things

1. Install Google Play services
2. Created a new app in Google Console, and got Google Map API key
3. Created new app in eclipse and added permission and Google Map API key in AndroidManifest.xml
4. Added Google Play Services library to App
5. Add a Map to the App (main.xml)
6. Set targeted API level 17

in my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

here is my complete source code
https://github.com/railskarthi/MapDemo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After API 11+, I think you now have have to replace your `MapFragment` by `SupportMapFragment`. It would be something like:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) for further information. Let me know how are you going with.

Comment: Yugi, I did two changes 1)extended my MainActivity from FragmentActivity instead of Activity 

2)in main.xml changed to

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Now map is working, but now I want to add Map view into Linear layout. How can I achieve it?(because here we extending from FragmentActivity)

Comment: @Karthi, Add your previous code inside a `LinearLayout` on your main.xml

Comment: Yugi, Your solution replacing MapFragment by SupportMapFragment, only worked in Windows environment. But in Mac OSX, still I am getting Error inflating class fragment error. Should I do anything different for Mac OSX?

Comment: Yugi, I did some mistake in adding Google Play Services library to App, now it is works fine in both Widows and Mac. Thanks for your response.

Comment: what if i added a custom fragment of my own rather than maps. How do i do it

Answer (score 1):

I have download your project from git and after checking i found that you have missed a line which is required to display map Fragment.

Replace your main activity code with the following code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could happen also if you did not define API_KEY for google maps in your manifest file.

It looks like this:

```
`....
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="<your key>" />
....`
```

Create your key in [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Please add these line in your manifest file

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your Goolge API key" />
```