# Can't get it working Google api 2 Android

Tags: android, maps

Even when i import:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

I am still getting this error messaging:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlev2map/com.example.googlev2map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
at com.example.googlev2map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
```

Doesn't work in my AVD, or directly on my Phone.
I import the google-play-services_lib and put the reference in this map project.
With min sdk 8...

Here is my coding,

My Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:id="@+id/map"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.googlev2map;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And my Manifest.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.googlev2map"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

            <permission
            android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>



        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.googlev2map.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
                  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBCn4SFyAoO9Enk39Zaq9-Gq25BGu7IsiU"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: may i know the error....

Comment: See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322567/error-inflating-class-fragment-android-map-v2 . Might be the same issue because you're targeting SDK 8.

Comment: I follow that answer, i  replace MapFragment by SupportMapFragment,but with no luck

Comment: I am targeting sdk 17, and i update the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about this code but i understand one thing that an answer was there in your error messaging. Please read your error message carefully. I have posted one line from your error message which explains your error as well as the **solution**.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's 
            AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
            Expected 4030500 but found 0.  
          You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     
           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: @levismad how did you make it work i have exactly the same problem