# Creating Google Map Project

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating a Google Maps project and I have api-key but when I want to run the app it stops working.

This is main layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="aref.org.walkingranking.MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this logcat error:
error is for wrong api-key and should use a integer but api-key is string

```
                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{aref.org.walkingranking/aref.org.walkingranking.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
                                                                           at aref.org.walkingranking.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:21)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.T(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.mA(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2115)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102) 
                                                                           at aref.org.walkingranking.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:21) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
10-28 16:01:35.983 1986-1998/aref.org.walkingranking I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1009(169KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 52% free, 937KB/1961KB, paused 172.239ms total 180.479ms
10-28 16:01:48.936 1986-1986/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1986 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please, post your logcat as text. Could you also post your layout XML?

Comment: add a second image too which shows the whole log clearly

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322567/error-inflating-class-fragment-android-map-v2

Comment: post your code...or check link which given by @Bhoomi

Comment: This has nothing to do with layout. The problem is that there isn't an api key in AndroidManifest.xml. See this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6171000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 0):

You must refer to a resource file in AndroidManifest.xml

As the error mentions:

```
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 6171000 but found 0. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: 
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

To solve this, you must add a resource file. 
The easiest way is to let Android Studio do this for you:

1. Right click on a package
2. Select New -> Activity -> Gallery
3. Press Google Map Activity
4. Open the resources (values/google_maps_api.xml)
5. Open the link from the file (https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?...)
6. Get the API key and set it as resource